# How to make a base system? -- Roblox Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a system to which when the player joins they are given a base and then no other players can use that base.

Here is my module inside the parented to the script:

```
local Functions = {}

function Functions.findOpenBase(plr)
    local bases = workspace.Bases
    for i,v in pairs(bases:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("Part") then
            print("Searching..")
            if plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value == false then
                if v.Owner.Value ~= nil then
                    print("Base found!")
                    v.Owner.Value = plr.Name
                    plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value = true
                else
                    warn("error")
                    plr:Kick("error finding base, Please Rejoin.")
                end
            end
        else
            print("cannot claim another base")
        end
    end
end

return Functions
```

then here is my handler script:

```
local module = require(script.Functions)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local alreadyOwnsBase = Instance.new("BoolValue", plr)
    alreadyOwnsBase.Name = "alreadyOwnsBase"
    alreadyOwnsBase.Value = false
    if plr then
        module.findOpenBase(plr)
        print(plr.Name)
    end
end)
```

is there any solutions?

Comment: The error is that when 2 players join only one is assigned a base

Answer (score 0):

To me, module inside the parented to the script:

```
local Functions = {}
function Functions.findOpenBase(plr)
    -- check it first.
    if plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value == false then
        local bases = workspace.Bases
        for i,v in pairs(bases:GetChildren()) do
            print("Searching..")
            if v:IsA("Part") then
                if v.Owner.Value ~= nil then
                    print("Base found!")
                    v.Owner.Value = plr.Name
                    plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value = true
                    -- get it, jump the loop
                    break
                end
            else
                print("cannot claim another base")
            end
        end
    end
    -- and plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value is the flag of the result
    if plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value == false then
        warn("error")
        plr:Kick("error finding base, Please Rejoin.")
    end
end

return Functions
```

and the handler script:

```
local module = require(script.Functions)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local alreadyOwnsBase = Instance.new("BoolValue", plr)
    alreadyOwnsBase.Name = "alreadyOwnsBase"
    alreadyOwnsBase.Value = false
    if plr then
        module.findOpenBase(plr)
        -- check the flag
        if plr.alreadyOwnsBase.Value then
            print(plr.Name)
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: so, when you run to ***plr:Kick("error finding base, Please Rejoin.")***, you should create a new base.